# No me carga la pagina index.php o server.php [Laravel 9]

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

necesito mucha ayuda con este problema que no puedo resolver hace 1 semana.
Resulta que mi proyecto corre todo bien en local, pero cuando subo a un servidor mediante FTP, me sale el siguiente mensaje de error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A modo de probar, borre todas las rutas de Routes/web.php para ver si ahi es el problema, pero creo que no es ahi, porque me sigue saliendo el mismo mensaje de error.

Mas abajo me sale estos mensajes:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Leyendo otros foros, supuestamente se arreglaria ejecutando [php artisan cache:clear]. Lamentablemente no puedo hacer eso, porque solo tengo acceso FTP hacia el servidor.

PD: no sé qué código de todo mi proyecto tendría que colocar como referencia, porque la verdad me tiene confundido.

Comment: Prueba eliminando los archivos dentro del directorio `bootstrap/cache` (en el servidor, claro) que se llamen como *config.php* y *routes.php* (o routes-vX.php, donde X es un número entero)

Comment: Recuerda también que no sólo puedes llamar comandos **Artisan** desde la consola, también puede llamarlos desde la acción de un controlador [programáticamente](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/artisan#programmatically-executing-commands)

Comment: También borra todo lo que esté en el directorio `storage/framework/cache/data` (igualmente en el servidor).

Comment: Muchas gracias @Josbert, borrando esas cosas que dijiste ya no me salio ese mensaje de error, pero me salio otro mensaje de denegacion de permisos, asi que le di permisos a dichas carpetas y ahora puedo ver por lo menos el Login :D yyeeahh, ahora me siguen saliendo mas mensajes de denegacion de permisos, supongo que tengo que seguir dando permisos a todos los archivos que me salga, enserio muchas gracias por todo amigo, voy a estar en eso, espero no tener mas problemas jeje

Comment: Por nada amigo, recuerda que **PHP** así como **Laravel** crean aplicaciones sin estado, por lo tanto naturalmente mantienen su caché en archivos, bases de datos o drivers similares. Son sencillas de vaciar pero esto las hace persistente, ojo allí ;)